# finding FIRST and FOLLOW for a set

Tags: compiler-construction

If I am finding FIRST for something like this:

```
begendcmds       :  CENTER  
                 |  VERBATIM  
                 |  SINGLE  
                 |  ITEMIZE  
                 |  ENUMERATE 
                 |  TABULAR  
                 |  TABLE
                 |  epsilon
                 ;
```

would it be FIRST(CENTER,epsilon) or FIRST(CENTER,VERBATIM)

Comment: Neither of the above.

Comment: is it (CENTER,VERBATIM,SINGLE,ITEMIZE,...,epsilon)?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. All the tokens that can be first in the production. IIRC

Comment: If `epsilon` represents the empty string, it is not a terminal and thus it is not an element of the FIRST set.